# How to remove id from this url?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I need to remove `/photo/26/` from this url `http://localhost/photo/26/h-house`

I already have removed `index.php` from all links.

Comment: Welcome to SO, to make your question more clear, could you please from which url(in browser) to which url(from backend) you want to serve it? To make your question more clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on asking a question that will make it more likely for you to get a response. In particular, ask a question and detail what steps you have taken to try to resolve and where you have looked for resources to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file using mod_rewrite to redirect `/photo/26/h-house` to `/h-house`, effectively *removing* `/photo/26` from the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^photo/26/h-house$ /h-house [R=302,L]
```

Or, to avoid repetition, you can do the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^photo/26(/h-house)$ $1 [R=302,L]
```

`$1` is a backreference that contains `/h-house` from the capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.